# Поиск значения в строке dataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, excel, datagridview

Такая проблема, не получается сделать поиск по строке в dataGridView. Я планировал делать так: я ищу строку в ячейке которой встречается "LUG" и начинаю работать с этой ячейкой.

Вид Excel файла:

[image: Excel]

Так его открывает dataGridView:

[image: dataGridView]

Ошибку выдает в строке:
`if (cell.Value.ToString().Contains("LUG"))`, ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

Обработка dataGridView:

```
 private void createHandover_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {                       
            string[] fromBs = new string[dataGridView1.Rows.Count];
            string[] fromFreq = new string[dataGridView1.Rows.Count];

            string[] toBs = new string[dataGridView1.Rows.Count];
            string[] toFreq = new string[dataGridView1.Rows.Count];

            //Убрать путь из имени файла
            openedFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(openedFileName);
            string fileName = $"handover{openedFileName}.txt";

            //Создание файла на рабочем столе
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter($"C:\\Users\\{Environment.UserName}\\Desktop\\" + fileName);

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    //Поиск строки в ряду
                    if (cell.Value.ToString().Contains("LUG"))
                    {
                        if (cell.ColumnIndex == 0) //Set your Column Index
                        {
                            fromBs[cell.RowIndex] += cell.Value;
                        }
                        if (cell.ColumnIndex == 1) //Set your Column Index
                        {
                            fromFreq[cell.RowIndex] += cell.Value;
                        }
                        if (cell.ColumnIndex == 2) //Set your Column Index
                        {
                            toBs[cell.RowIndex] += cell.Value;
                        }
                        if (cell.ColumnIndex == 3) //Set your Column Index
                        {
                            toFreq[cell.RowIndex] += cell.Value;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //Удаление пустых значений из массива
            fromBs = fromBs.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
            fromFreq = fromFreq.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
            toBs = toBs.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
            toFreq = toFreq.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();

            //Замена первого столбца
            for (int i = 0; i < fromBs.Length; i++)
            {
                if (fromBs[i].Contains("_1"))
                    fromBs[i] = fromBs[i].Replace("_1", "A");
                if (fromBs[i].Contains("_2"))
                    fromBs[i] = fromBs[i].Replace("_2", "B");
                if (fromBs[i].Contains("_3"))
                    fromBs[i] = fromBs[i].Replace("_3", "C");
            }

            //Замена второго столбца
            for (int i = 0; i < toBs.Length; i++)
            {
                if (toBs[i].Contains("_1"))
                    toBs[i] = toBs[i].Replace("_1", "A");
                if (toBs[i].Contains("_2"))
                    toBs[i] = toBs[i].Replace("_2", "B");
                if (toBs[i].Contains("_3"))
                    toBs[i] = toBs[i].Replace("_3", "C");
            }

            //Запись в файл
            for (int i = 0; i < fromBs.Length; i++)
            {
                sw.Write("RLNRI:CELL=" + fromBs[i] + ", CELLR=" + toBs[i] + ";" + Environment.NewLine);
                if (i + 1 == fromBs.Length)
                {
                    sw.Write(Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < fromBs.Length; i++)
            {
                //Обрезка строки и сравнение
                if (fromBs[i].Trim(new char[] { 'A', 'B', 'C' }) == toBs[i].Trim(new char[] { 'A', 'B', 'C' }))
                {
                    sw.Write("RLNRC:CELL=" + fromBs[i] + ", CELLR=" + toBs[i] + ",CAND=BOTH,CS=YES,KHYST=6,KOFFSETP=0," +
                    "LHYST=8,LOFFSETP=0,TRHYST=4,TROFFSETP=0,AWOFFSET=10,BQOFFSET=10;" + Environment.NewLine);
                }
                else
                {
                    sw.Write("RLNRC:CELL=" + fromBs[i] + ", CELLR=" + toBs[i] + ",CAND=BOTH,CS=NO,KHYST=6,KOFFSETP=0," +
                        "LHYST=8,LOFFSETP=0,TRHYST=4,TROFFSETP=0,AWOFFSET=10,BQOFFSET=10;" + Environment.NewLine);
                }
                if (i + 1 == fromBs.Length)
                {
                    sw.Write(Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < fromBs.Length; i++)
            {
                sw.Write("RLMFC:CELL=" + fromBs[i] + ", MBCCHNO=" + toFreq[i] + ",MRNIC;" + Environment.NewLine);
                if (i + 1 == fromBs.Length)
                {
                    sw.Write(Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < fromBs.Length; i++)
            {
                sw.Write("RLMFC:CELL=" + toBs[i] + ", MBCCHNO=" + fromFreq[i] + ",MRNIC;" + Environment.NewLine);
            }

            //dataGridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[columnindex].Value.ToString();

            sw.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            return;
        }
        finally
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Created.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: `cell.Value?.ToString().Contains("LUG")` - надо проверять есть ли значение в ячейке, прежде чем пытаться сделать `ToString()`

Comment: Вы мне опять помогли! Спасибо вам большое!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все решилось добавлением проверки на наличие значения в ячейке, как советовал Bulson

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                //Проверка 1-го столбца на пустоту
                if (row.Cells[0].Value != null)
                {
                    //Если в 1м и 3ем столбец есть не пустой и в нем есть LUG или LU
                    if ((row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Contains("LUG") || row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Contains("LU"))
                        && (row.Cells[2].Value.ToString().Contains("LUG") || row.Cells[2].Value.ToString().Contains("LU")))
                    {
                        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                        {
                            if (cell.ColumnIndex == 0) //Set your Column Index
                            {
                                fromBs[cell.RowIndex] += cell.Value;
                            }
                            if (cell.ColumnIndex == 1) //Set your Column Index
                            {
                                fromFreq[cell.RowIndex] += cell.Value;
                            }
                            if (cell.ColumnIndex == 2) //Set your Column Index
                            {
                                toBs[cell.RowIndex] += cell.Value;
                            }
                            if (cell.ColumnIndex == 3) //Set your Column Index
                            {
                                toFreq[cell.RowIndex] += cell.Value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```